# PyQT4: Another way to VIEW CODE in Qt Designer?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, python-3.6, qt-designer

Is there another way to view code dynamically in Qt Designer instead of converting `.ui` files to `.py` files manually?

[image: Qt Designer, ScreenCap]

Comment: The file `.ui` is an XML file. You can open it via any editor and see the code.

Comment: use any text editor and you will see that the .ui is an .xml

Answer (score 1):

I am using the pyqt5_tools package from pip in windows and was able to get the 'view code' tool in qt designer to work by copying the pyuic5.exe from the \scripts\ folder of the python install and putting it in the \Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\bin\ folder and renaming it uic.exe. The 'view code' command will now display python code.

If you are using a different version or this doesn't seem to work try running the qtpaths.exe (\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools) in command line with '--binaries-dir' params and this will show you where you should put the renamed pyuic5.exe.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The .ui files are actually XML files and can be opened with anything capable of displaying text.

There isn't really **code** in them, though. Just UI definition data.
But that might depend on your definition of code ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking about the View Code tool in Qt Designer, which uses `uic` to generate C++ ui code and display it in a editor window. They want to know if the same thing can be done for `pyuic` so that it shows the equivalent Python code. The answer to which is, of course: No.

Comment: That might indeed be what the OP is asking, but I would say it is one of many ways to interpret the rather vague question. You're free to add your own answer.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, but I think there's no another way to view dynamically from the QT designer to a python code. So I've no choice but convert it manually in the cmd.